# Qual a origem do verbo "azoratar"

Tags: etimologia

Estava procurando o significado de zureta e acabei deparando com o verbo [azoratar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/azoratar). Procurando a etimologia, vi que tem relação com [orate](https://aulete.com.br/orate) (de origem catalão). No entanto, não entendi o "az" que compõe este verbo. Como de Orate muda para azoratar? Encontrei [este link](https://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/curiosidades_verbais_-_cams_-_para_internet.pdf) (pg. 200), considerando que seja Casa dos Orates e não "de Orates".
Além disto, pode ter outra origem?

Comment: A página 201 da referência citada já aventa outra possibilidade, tida como mais provável: açor (azor) -> açorar -> açoratar/azoratar; e também cita, na nota de rodapé #2 dessa página, a etimologia dada pelo Lindolfo Gomes, zurita, pomba bravia (esp. zorita; galego zurita).

Comment: Outras fontes subscrevem a etimologia "Casa dos Orates". A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/zorate), e.g., coloca: "De os orates, por mal-entendido"; o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/azoratar) dá (a- + zorate + -ar), com ([o]s orate[s]) para "zorate"; e o Houaiss escreve "Nasc e JM admitem étimo proposto por Leite de Vasconcelos: da redução de _casa dos orates_ teria sido depreendido o segmento _zorate_; tomado como vocábulo, _zorate_ seria a base radical do verbo derivado _a- + zorat(e) + -ar_; o adjetivo _azoratado_ datamos de 1871".

Comment: @stafusa sabe de onde pomba vira doido (enlouquecido)? Se procurar "dos Orates", acha menos entradas no Google que "de Orates".

Comment: Sim, o João Ribeiro é convincente em sua crítica à proposta "dos Orates". Sobre a pomba não tenho mais informação.